# Random Graphics Card Failure Upon Startup

Tags: graphics-card

My graphics card is a MSI Ventus 3x 3070, if that helps.
I've had a problem yesterday and today, where after using my computer and turning it off, leaving it a while, and upon turning it on again the graphics card won't work.

The VGA debug light on the monitor lights up and stays on, and my monitor is black save for a white underscore below the top left of the screen. Even after turning it off and on again the graphics card won't respond, and only after leaving it overnight did the graphics card respond again.

It then happened again, and I tried taking the graphics card out of the PCIE slot and putting it back in again and it worked. What might be the problem here? The graphics card or the motherboard?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I doubt that we have enough information to make a definitive judgement what is to blame until you've done a bit more troubleshooting and possibly dust cleaning.

Comment: It could be a contact in the socket, it could be the soldering of the socket to the motherboard, or other issue. BTW, after a long time, a PCB socket connection can go bad, an be fixed be reseating the device. One cause: photomicrograph I've seen showed how fungal mycelium can squeeze into a board-edge connector!